# java.io.EOFException after upgrading to MySQL 5.6 and restoring a database when re-running unit test

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, mysql5, mysql-5.6

I have a Java application and we upgraded to MySQL 5.6.  When I restore a database that was dumped previously using mysqldump using `mysql <` and try to re-run a unit test in IntelliJ I receive the following exception -

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3166)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3620)
    ... 78 more
```

I can connect successfully using the mysql command line client.

MySQL is 5.6.16 Homebrew.

JDBC driver is MySQL Connector/J 5.1.29.

OS is OS X 10.9.2 (13C64).

If I restart MySQL, this fixes the problem. The answer I am looking for for this question is how to avoid this restart. Thanks.

Comment: can you paste the error_log. It should give you info enough.

Comment: Nothing in the log_error. I did rm *.err, mysqldump, re-run, and the .err file was never created.